# JS - D3 Multiline time series chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I need to make a time series style graphic, with D3, multiple. Taking this example as a basis: [example](https://bl.ocks.org/jqadrad/a58719d82741b1642a2061c071ae2375)

The code is the following:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var data =  [{fecha: "2019-03-16", partidos: "1", goles: "0", tarjetas: "0"},
        {fecha: "2019-03-23", partidos: "1", goles: "1", tarjetas: "0"},
        {fecha: "2019-03-30", partidos: "1", goles: "0", tarjetas: "1"},
        {fecha: "2019-04-06", partidos: "0", goles: "0", tarjetas: "0"},
        {fecha: "2019-04-13", partidos: "1", goles: "2", tarjetas: "0"},
                        ];          

    // Draw a line chart
    var svg = d3.select('#graf_act_tiempo'),
        margin = { top: 20, right: 50, bottom: 30, left: 50 },
        width = +svg.attr('width') - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = +svg.attr('height') - margin.top - margin.bottom,
        g = svg.append('g').attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');

    // Function to convert a string into a time
    var parseTime = d3.time.format('%Y-%m-%d').parse;

    // Set the X scale
    var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width], 0.5);
    // Set the Y scale
    var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);
    // Set the color scale
    var color = d3.scale.category10();

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom")
    .tickSize(6, 0)
    .tickFormat(d3.time.format('%d/%m/%y'));

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .tickSize(1, 0)
    .tickFormat(d3.format("d"));

    var line = d3.svg.line()
    // .interpolate("basis")
    .x(function(d) {
      return x(d.fecha);
    })
    .y(function(d) {
      return y(d.worth);
    });

    // load the data
    // Select the important columns
    color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) {
        return key !== "fecha";
    }));
    // Correct the types
    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.fecha = parseTime(d.fecha);
    });
    //console.log(data);

      var currencies = color.domain().map(function(name) {
        return {
          name: name,
          values: data.map(function(d) {
            return {
              fecha: d.fecha,
              worth: +d[name]
            };
          })
        };
      });
      //console.log(currencies)
      // Set the X domain
      x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
        return d.fecha;
      }));

      // Set the Y domain
      y.domain([
        d3.min(currencies, function(c) {
          return d3.min(c.values, function(v) {
            return v.worth;
          });
        }),
        d3.max(currencies, function(c) {
          return d3.max(c.values, function(v) {
            return v.worth;
          });
        })
      ]);

      // Set the X axis
      g.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis)
        .selectAll("text")  
            .style("text-anchor", "end")
            .attr("dx", "-.8em")
            .attr("dy", ".15em")
            .attr("transform", "rotate(-65)");
      // Set the Y axis
      g.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis)
        .append("text")
//      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("y", 0)
        .attr("x", 60)
        .attr("dy", "4px")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .text("Cantidad");

      // Draw the lines
      var currency = g.selectAll(".currency")
        .data(currencies)
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "currency");

      currency.append("path")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", function(d) {
          return line(d.values);
        })
        .style("stroke", function(d) {
          return color(d.name);
        });
      // Add the circles
      currency.append("g").selectAll("circle")
        .data(function(d){return d.values})
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr("r", 2)
        .attr("cx", function(dd){return x(dd.fecha)})
        .attr("cy", function(dd){return y(dd.worth)})
        .attr("fill", "none")
        .attr("stroke", function(d){return color(this.parentNode.__data__.name)});

        // Add label to the end of the line
      currency.append("text")
        .attr("class", "label")
        .datum(function (d) {
          return {
            name: d.name,
            value: d.values[d.values.length - 1]
          };
        })
        .attr("transform", function (d) {
          return "translate(" + x(d.value.fecha) + "," + y(d.value.worth) + ")";
        })
        .attr("x", 6)
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .text(function (d) {
          return d.name;
      });

    </script>
```

The following result is obtained:
[image]

I need help to make these changes:

1) The legend "cantidad" of the "y" axis located above the maximum value of the axis (top) or left of axis.

2) The values of the "x" axis that are not cut, that can be read well

Thanks for the tips to improve it.

Answer (score -1):

1) Add more value left to svg and .attr("x", -20) to y axis
2) Add more valur bottom to svg